# How to use multiprocessing pool for a multivariable function python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, python-multiprocessing, pool

I'm trying to use the library multiprocessing, to run the next code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def newtalt(fun,x0,err,mit):

    xnew = x0.copy()
    F, dF = fun(x0)

    r = F.copy()
    M = dF.copy()

    sigma = np.linalg.norm(r)

    for k in range(mit):

        if sigma < err:
            break

        d = np.linalg.solve(M, -r)
        xnew = xnew + d
        r, M = fun(xnew)
        sigma = np.linalg.norm(r)

    return xnew, k

def fun(x):

    f_r = x[0] ** 3 - 3 * x[0] * (x[1] ** 2) - 1
    f_i = 3 * (x[0]**2) * x[1] - (x[1] ** 3)
    f = np.array([f_r,f_i])

    df_rx = 3 * (x[0] ** 2) - 3 * (x[1] ** 2)
    df_ry = -6 * x[0] * x[1]
    df_ix = 6 * x[0] * x[1]
    df_iy = 3 * (x[0] ** 2) - 3 * (x[1] ** 2)
    df = np.array([[df_rx,df_ry],[df_ix,df_iy]])

    return f, df

if __name__=='__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=10)

    err = 1e-5
    mit = 300
    N = 50

    x = np.linspace(-2.5, 2.5, N)
    y = np.linspace(-2.5, 2.5, N)
    A = np.zeros((N, N))
    B = np.zeros([N, N, 4], dtype=int)

    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            z = np.array([x[i], y[j]])

            xsol, it = pool.map(newtonalt,(fun,z,err,mit))
            pool.close()

            A[i,j] = it

    plt.imshow(A,cmap='Set1')
    plt.show()
```

Cleary it doesn't work, 'cause I don't really know how to use multiprocessing properly, and it's even more difficult when the function you use have multiple arguments. I read that isn't good use .pool() inside a for loop, but anyway, as I was saying, I'm really lost with this library.

Comment: You might want to use `apply` instead of `map`: `pool.apply(newtonalt, (fun, z, err, mit))`

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.